# Call Function After signin-oidc login in DotNet Core ASP Web App

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-cognito

I am building an asp.net core web app with Amazon Cognito using Open Id Connect. I have everything working well in the normal scope of that setup.  My question is, how do I identify and trigger an event each time that someone successfully signs in.  My Callback URL is set to /signin-oidc, How can I override/extend the controller and action at the /signin-oidc endpoint so that I can take action at that point to create my user profile?

My OAuth 2.0 Flows/Scopes are the following:
[image]

Comment: Which OIDC flow do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could solve this by adding an `OnTicketReceived` event to `services.AddOpenIdConnect(...)`.  I redirect successful logins to a `public IActionResult CheckProfile(string url) {...}` where I determine if the user can continue to the requested url or if they get redirected into a create profile workflow.

This post was helpful: https://community.auth0.com/t/handle-new-user-signup-in-asp-net-core/18724

I like my solution because I am only taking action each time the user successfully logs in.

Here is what I added to ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        ...
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTicketReceived = e =>
            {
                e.ReturnUri = string.Format("/Home/CheckProfile?url={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.ReturnUri));
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
    ...
}
```

I realize that there are other ways to do this.  I looked at a custom IAuthorizationPolicyProvider. It would add a ton more flexibility, but I just needed a simple redirect and OnTicketReceived works.